# I can't get the data using Rules on scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

i'm doing a spider with scrapy that works if i don't implement any rules, but now i'm trying to implement a Rule to get paginator and scrape all the rest of pages. But i don't know why i can't achieve it.

Spider code:

```
    allowed_domains = ['guia.bcn.cat']
    start_urls = ['http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=*:*']

rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index.php?pg=search&from=10&q=*:*&nr=10"),
        restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='paginador']",))
        , callback="parse_item", follow=True),)

def parse_item(self, response)
...
```

Also, i tried to set "index.php" in allow parameter of the rule, but neither works.

I read in scrapy groups that i have not put "a/" or "a/@href" because SgmlLinkExtractor search automatically the link.

Console output seems to work well but don't get anything.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

With this code works

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from bcncat.items import BcncatItem
import re

class BcnSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bcn'
    allowed_domains = ['guia.bcn.cat']
    start_urls = ['http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=*:*']


rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(re.escape("index.php")),
            restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='paginador']")),
        callback="parse_item",
        follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log("parse_item")
    sel = Selector(response)
    i = BcncatItem()
    #i['domain_id'] = sel.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').extract()
    #i['name'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract()
    #i['description'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').extract()
    return i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allow` parameter for `SgmlLinkExtractor` is a (list of) regular expression(s). So "?", "*" and "." are treated as special characters.

You can use `allow=(re.escape("index.php?pg=search&from=10&q=*:*&nr=10"))` (with `import re` somewhere at the beginning of your script)

EDIT: in fact, the above rule doesn't work. But as you already have the restricted region where you want to extract links, you can use `allow=('index.php')`

Comment: If i use `allow=('index.php')` it doesn't do anything

Comment: I uploaded a sample CrawlSpider and console.log: https://gist.github.com/redapple/8405909

Comment: Now it works!

Maybe was about lines indexation.. 

I don't know how python exactly works but if i uncomment  one item line `#i['domain_id'] = sel.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').extract()` sometimes console shows **Indexation Error** and to fix it i have to quit a tab space. Is it normal? Is a newbie error? Thanks a lot for your reply and work!

Comment: With Python, indentation of code is essential, and mixing TABs and space characters leads to these errors. Either indent with TABs everywhere, or N-spaces everywhere, and stick to it. (personally I use 4-spaces.)

Comment: Only on more question: why the output json is giving to me something like this `{"title": [Film1], ...` instead of `{"title": Film1, ...` or if i export in xml format i have: `<title><value>Film1</value></title>` instead of `<title>Film1</title>`? I'm asking this because then i have to import in solr and it's more clear withoud [] or <value> fields.

Comment: `.extract()` on a Selector or SelectorList returns a list of unicode strings ([see the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#module-scrapy.selector)), so you either need to select the first element of the returned list (e.g. `sel.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract()[0]`) or you can serialize the list using something like `u''.join(sel.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract())`